# angular-cli new angularjs2 project error message

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed latest angular cli from webpack. create the sample project and running it. during start-up its giving error message, but application works.

I like to clear this start up error message.

installed angular cli like this.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli 

npm cache clean

npm install -g angular-cli@webpack
```

**error message.**

```
WARNING in (webpack)/buildin/module.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
* c:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    c:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\rxjs\util\root.js

ERROR in [default]
Cannot find global type 'Array'.

ERROR in [default]
Cannot find global type 'Boolean'.

ERROR in [default]
Cannot find global type 'Function'.

ERROR in [default]
Cannot find global type 'IArguments'.

ERROR in [default]
Cannot find global type 'Number'.

ERROR in [default]
Cannot find global type 'Object'.

ERROR in [default]
Cannot find global type 'RegExp'.

ERROR in [default]
Cannot find global type 'String'.

ERROR in [default] C:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_class.d.ts:81:33
Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [default] C:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_if.d.ts:37:76
Cannot find name 'Object'.

ERROR in [default] C:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_plural.d.ts:78:53
Cannot find name 'Object'.

ERROR in [default] C:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_switch.d.ts:12:79
Cannot find name 'Object'.
```

How can I clear this error message?

thanks
SR

Comment: C:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
c:\shared\ang2boot\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js

Drive C: in different casing. Not sure what causing this.

Comment: ang2boot is the project name, I created in c:\shared directory.

Comment: Something somewhere uses capital C for drive name. Do search in all files, see where it is.

Answer (score 0):

after couple of days I uninstalled and re-installed angular-cli and created new project. it works now.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli 

npm cache clean

npm install -g angular-cli@webpack
```